# lua use gsub or match for end substring deletion?

Tags: optimization, lua, substring

Let's have a `/file/path/name` and we need to get the parent directory of that file in the most performant way. What is the most optimal way to strip the filename from that string?

My ideas:

- `gsub('[^/]+$','')`
- `gsub('/[^/]+$','/')`
- `match('^.+/')`

Comment: Define "most performant". How long are your strings?

Comment: Why don't you just benchmark your ideas? I would expect the `match` to be fastest.

Comment: @lhf well, not very, considering it is a path, maybe 100-150 chars.